# Scala: Play - count child nodes in Json

Tags: json, scala, playframework, children

I have json as

```
val json = 
{
   "header" : "header value"
   "value" : [
        {
         "a" : "a_val"
         "b" : "b_val"
         "c" : "c_val"
        },
        {
         "a" : "a_val"
         "b" : "b_val"
         "c" : "c_val"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to calculate the

1. count of records i.e. 2, which i count

   `(json \\ "value")(0).asOpt[JsArray].map(_.value.size).getOrElse(0)`

   Tedius, but works. Simpler solution is needed
2. count of child nodes in `value`, i.e. 3 (`a, b and c`)

No idea how to count this

EDIT: 
Using Daniels Solution: I simplified count of records as

`(oDataJson \ "value").as[JsArray].value.size`

Comment: Which json library do you use?

Comment: What if the child nodes have differing sizes? e.g. one of them does not have a `c` ?

Comment: @Reactormonk.. I m using Play Framework

Comment: @m-z .. that's not in my case of json.. i have standard structure of json that actually takes records from database. So, it does have same structure for all records

Comment: What's the point of counting how many fields, if you already know what the structure is, and how many there are?

Comment: It's based on the query. If I return all the fields, i dont know how many fields are there. But they are same through all the records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  (json \\ "value").headOption match {
    case Some(JsArray(values)) => values.length
    case _ => 0
  }
  // => 2

  (json \\ "value").headOption match {
    case Some(JsArray(Seq(JsObject(fields), _*))) => fields.size
    case _ => 0
  }
  // => 3
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel. It does give expected results.